# Add dynamic tabs in tabbed property view of eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to create a tabbed property view as per given article : [The Eclipse Tabbed Properties View](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html)

As per article, `org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs` extension point can be used to add new tabs.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs">
      <propertyTabs contributorId="mview.views.SampleView">
         <propertyTab
            category="sample"
               id="mview.ButtonTab"
            label="Button"/>
         <propertyTab
            afterTab="mview.ButtonTab"
            category="sample"
               id="mview.AdvancedTab"
            label="Advanced"/>
      </propertyTabs>
   </extension>
```

However in my case the tabs of property view vary depending on the item selected in view. So I have to add the tabs dynamically into extension depening on the item selected.

Please suggest how to do so.

Update:
One of the way to do so (I am not sure if its adviced) is using IExtensionRegistry.addContribution() method. Here I provided an inputstream object containing desired extension details. This added tabs to property view at run time. However with change in selection of item in list viewer, the property view is not updated. Please suggest if this is the right approach to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution Its a two step process. Using this one can dyanamically add tabs (and their sections):

**Step 1: Associate a tab descriptor provider with the view.**

Add an extension point - `org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyContributor` to the view (if not already added). In the propertyContributor section, add a class for tabDescriptorProvider item. This class will implement ITabDescriptorProvider interface.

**Step 2: Provide Tabs and Sections:**

TabDescriptor provider will return array of TabDescriptors when its getTabDescriptor() method is called. Each TabDescriptor return a list of SectionDecriptors and each SectionDescriptor is linked to a Section. Finally it is the Section class that contains widgets to be displayed on screen. Each widget in Section class has a modify listner which updates the properties of selected items.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from *Viral* may not match the specific needs of the OP, the provided answer is likely acceptable to many.

If a tab does not have any sections to display, the default `TabbedPropertySheetPage` will not show that tab. Thus, if the problem domain is specified in terms of `IFilter` implementing classes, "dynamic" tabs may be achieved.

Tabs will be added or be removed as the selection changes depending upon whether any sections are present. A visible tab may have one or more sections present on it, and the number of sections on a visible tab may change from selection to selection.

As I came across this page with the same basic issue, I was a bit disappointed that I would need to intervene in the way the OP suggested. After some experimentation, I was able to achieve what I needed purely through the `IFilter` approach as suggested by *Viral*.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial is provided at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html

You need to define a new YourPropertySection derived fromAbstract `PropertySection` . Also define a filter derived from `IFilter` and override the `select` method to return true only for the desired type of selection. Then in plugin.xml write an extension point which would map your PropertySection to the required PropertyTab and will also associate your filter. So this section & tab will only show when your filter returns true.

Comment: Thanks Viral for your answer. Your solution guides how to make a section dynamic, however, I have to make tabs. Once a tab is displayed, it will automatically have predefined section. Currently I am trying to provide a custom tabDescriptorProvider which will (based on selection) add desired tabs to list. I think I am missing something on this approach as properties are still not getting displayed.